# Why does this java code to count digit of floating value goes in loop for this value?

Tags: java, count, floating-point, digits

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class FloatDigit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n = sc.nextDouble();
        int x = (int) n;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            count++;
            x = x / 10;
        } while (x != 0);

        System.out.println("Before Decimal Digits: " + count); 
        //it gets stuck from here only

        do {
            count++;
            n = n * 10;
        } while (n != (int) n);
        System.out.println(count + " total digits present in there in number.");
    }
}
```

This goes in an infinite loop for the value: 58.2354/58.234. It is working fine with other values too and longer values too.

Comment: Try running your code in a debugger, so that you can step through it line by line and see what the values of variables are at each point in the code. Or try adding `System.out.println(...);` statements at strategic points to understand what's happening.

Comment: using binary floating point types (e.g. `float` or `double`) cause a number of implementation artifacts for you to deal with. using `BigDecimal` might be more suitable unless you're specifically learning about ieee754 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some debug logging is added to the second loop, it can be seen, that when multiplying a `double` number by 10, there is a tiny error which does not allow the comparison `n == (int) n` ever become true.

It is actually a known issue that floating-point arithmetics has a certain computation error, so it should be taken into account when comparing the `double n` to its counterpart with the decimal point shifted right:

```java
do {
    count++;
    n = n * 10;
    System.out.println(count + " - " + n);
} while (Math.abs(n - (int) n) > 1E-7);

System.out.println(count + " total digits present in the number.");
```

Output:

```
58.234
Before Decimal Digits: 2
3 - 582.34
4 - 5823.400000000001
5 - 58234.00000000001
5 total digits present in the number.
```